# RSA: Given two very large prime $p,q$ and $n=p\;q$, how to quickly find $e$ such that $\gcd(\varphi(n),e)=1$?

Tags: rsa, keys

I can imagine that finding $p,q,n$ are easy, but my text book also says the $e$ can be found rapidly, so how does modern RSA find this $e$?

[image: RSA as a Public Key System]

Comment: You can find $e$ by finding the constant number $2^{16} + 1$ (you pick e). You then find $d$, which is another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $p$ and $q$ distinct primes and $n=p\;q$, it holds that $\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$. Having $e$ relatively prime to $\varphi(n)$ means that $\gcd(\varphi(n),e)=1$, and that's equivalent to: $\gcd(p-1,e)=1=\gcd(q-1,e)$.

Notice that if both $p$ and $q$ are large primes, their are odd, thus $p-1$ and $q-1$ are even, thus $e$ must be odd for $\gcd(p-1,e)=1=\gcd(q-1,e)$ to hold.

There are several methods to pick $p$, $q$, $e$, including:

1. Pick prime $p$; pick prime $q\ne p$; then pick an (odd) $e>1$ until it verifies $\gcd(p-1,e)=1=\gcd(q-1,e)$. Moving to $e+2$ if $e$ is not suitable (and checking that new $e$ again) will do, and few tries will typically be necessary [but see note final note].
2. First pick odd $e>1$; then pick prime $p$ with $\gcd(p-1,e)=1$; then pick prime $p\ne q$ with $\gcd(q-1,e)=1$.

In both methods, it helps to choose $e$ prime, because the test $\gcd(p-1,e)=1$ simplifies to $p\bmod e\ne1$, and is more likely to succeed than with a composite $e$ of comparable magnitude. There also are reasons to choose $e$ not too large, because that strongly tends to speed-up raising to the $e^\text{th}$ power. Thus we often end up choosing $e$ a small prime, often one of the 5 Fermat primes $F_i=2^{(2^i)}+1$ with $0\le i<5$, which further simplifies raising to the $e^\text{th}$.

For very small odd prime $e$, the second method can be performed as follows: having fixed $e$, we choose secret $f_p$ uniformly randomly in $\{2,\dots,e-1\}$, and explore only candidate primes $p$ of the form $p=2k\;e+(((f_p+1)\bmod 2)\;e+f_p)$.

---

Note: Starting from a known fixed $e$ and moving to $e+2$ if $e$ if not acceptable reveals something about $p$ or $q$. For example, if we see $e=259$ for one key when most others generated in the same way have $e=257$, we know that $p$ or $q$ for that key is of the form $514k+1$. In practice, that does not matter much AFAIK, because efficient factorization algorithms do not exploit such partial knowledge.

Comment: It's a little be unclear for me what you meant that $e$ picked reveals something about $p$ and $q$. But I appreciate your answer! I'm trying to understand it.

Comment: And It seems like $e$ could not be too small, since the chance $e \mid (p-1)$ or $e \mid (q-1)$ will increase.

Comment: @Ning: Yes, small $e$ (in particular $e=3$) require method 2.

Answer (score 0):

Normall practice is to pick public exponent as a small prime(preferably with few set bits in binary representstion). If the public exponent is prime we only need to verify it doesn't devide $\phi(n)$.